# What's wrong with my binomial logistic regression model please? (SPSS)

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, spss, binary-data

I am running a binary logistic regression in SPSS (standard, no stepwise) containing 20 predictors (binary and continuous) and have the following problems:
1) it correctly classifies ~the same % as the null model (87.2% null vs 87.1% full model)
2) Sensitivity was 6.8%!!! Specificity was 98.9%, positive predictive value was 47.6% and negative predictive value was 87.8%.

The sample size is just over N=9,000. There were 427 standardized residual with values over 2.5 standard deviations, which were retained in the analysis. The logistic regression model was statistically significant, χ2(22) = 906.74, p < .001. The model explained 17.4% (Nagelkerke R2) of the variance.

I have run a Pearson's correlation matrix and not detected anything strange (all values below r=0.7). I tried removing some of the variables to see whether I could improve the model but it remained the same.

Any advice on what the problem might be/what I should do next would be great. I'm a newbie to stats so apologies if I have missed anything obvious!

Comment: Accuracy (correct classification) is not a good way to assess logistic regression. Don't look at that.

Comment: What, specifically, is the problem - these are the results you have. Why don't you like them?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and this gives me hope. I am happy to accept it if the model is working as it should (even if I dont like the results, of course!), however the accuracy not changing compared to the null model, and the low sensitivity worried me (my experience of sensitivity and specificity is with testing something against a gold standard, not use in a regression model, and I was just thinking that the % accurate should be higher if the full model is better than the null). This just comes down to me being new to the details of running a regression. Thank you

Comment: % accurate is selected at an arbitrary cutoff of 50% (by SPSS). It's better to calculate the c-statistic (area under the curve).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy I have run a ROC analysis and it says the area under the curve is 0.760 (95%CI 0.746-0.774) which I understand to mean it is a 'good' model. Much appreciated.